# Queue ADT using linked list Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, queue, implementation

Using Java, I am trying to write a Queue ADT using a circular linked list (I believe I used the correct terminology, feel free to correct me if I am wrong!). The problem is that when I try to call the `front` method in the `Queue` class, it returns a `NullPointerException` error.

```
class Node 
    {
  private Object item;
  private Node next;

  public Node(Object newItem) {
    item = newItem;
    next = null;
  } // end constructor

  public Node(Object newItem, Node nextNode) {
    item = newItem;
    next = nextNode;
  } // end constructor

  public void setItem(Object newItem) {
    item = newItem;
  } // end setItem

  public Object getItem() {
    return item;
  } // end getItem

  public void setNext(Node nextNode) {
    next = nextNode;
  } // end setNext

  public Node getNext() {
    return next;
  } // end getNext

} // end class Node

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class Queue {

    protected Node lastNode;

     Queue(){ 
         lastNode = null; 
    }//End default constructor 

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
        return (lastNode == null); 
    }//End isEmpty

    public void dequeueAll() {
    //Deletes the full queue since the pointer goes nowhere 
        lastNode = null; 
    }

    public void enqueue(Object item) { 
        Node newNode = new Node(item);

        if ( isEmpty() )
            lastNode = newNode; 
        else 
            lastNode.setNext(newNode);

    }
    public void dequeue() { 

        if ( !(isEmpty()) )
            lastNode.setNext(lastNode.getNext().getNext());
        else 
            throw new QueueException("QueueException on dequeue:" + "queue empty");
    }

    public Object front() { 

      if ( !(isEmpty()) ) { 
          Node firstNode = lastNode.getNext();
          return (firstNode.getItem());
      } 
      else { 
          throw new QueueException("QueueException on front:" + "queue empty");

      }
   }    
}
```

Here is my attempt (Node class being used is included at the top). 
I believe my problem lies within the `enqueue` method as I do not think I am linking the list correctly. I've tried looking for a similar idea elsewhere but I haven't found many examples that I could follow in Java. If anyone could give me some pointers, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: This implementation's front() method won't work if lastNode is the only node in the queue, because then firstNode would be null, and you can't do null.getItem(); I would think that's the issue.

Comment: Another thing; you're not really implementing your queue as a circular linked list. Your front() method is just returning the second element in the list. I would just make the queue like a singular-linked list, renaming lastNode to head and storing both head (really the front of the Queue) and rear (back of the Queue) as Nodes as members of the Queue class (rear used for insertion, head used for removal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean isEmpty() { 
        return (lastNode == null); 
    }//End isEmpty
```

This method checks if the lastNode == null . However,

```
      Node firstNode = lastNode.getNext();
```

If lastNode is not NULL , lastNode.getNext() can be NULL.You should check that before calling lastNode.getNext().

Comment: I appreciate this! I actually hadn't thought of that instance. However, the problem I was observing had been happening when there were elements in the Queue.